# iOS: Centering an UIImageView in a wide UIView

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, uiimageview

I have a small `UIImageView` and wish to centre it horizontally inside a `UIView` which is as wide as the screen.

I also wish to have the UIImageView stay centered when the device rotates.

How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will center `imageView` horizontally within `view`:

```
imageView.frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(imageView.bounds)
```

This will ensure that `imageView` stays horizontally centered when its superview's bounds change:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleRightMargin
```

Comment: No, because the center property is in the superview's coordinate system (like the frame property). If the origin of `view.frame` is 0, 0 this will work but better not to rely on that.

Comment: Hahaha yes of course. I tried to delete my comment before you noticed that I'm an idiot.

Comment: a UIView's frame is readonly, just like its x property... Setting the frame with CGRectMake() and using those functions for origin.x will work.

Comment: Resizing within both enumerated options needs to be lowercase.